# R combine multiple txt files and format matrix

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have 28 files with two columns each that looks like this:

```
 165654 25
 536619 26
 886914 27
 592837 28
 457213 29
2462004 30
1278237 31
 100659 32
  72829 33
  11249 34
   4136 35
```

Where the first column is a read count and the second is read length.  I am trying to combine the 28 files in R into a matrix that looks like this:

[image]

but I am having trouble with the final steps, so far I have tried this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.txt$", 
                            full.names = TRUE)
DT <- rbindlist(sapply(list_of_files, fread, simplify = FALSE),
                use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")

dput(DT)
structure(list(FileName = c("./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1a_S1_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1b_S8_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1c_S15_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC1d_S22_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2a_S2_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2b_S9_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2c_S16_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC2d_S23_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3a_S3_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3b_S10_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3c_S17_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC3d_S24_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4a_S4_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4b_S11_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4c_S18_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC4d_S25_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5a_S5_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5b_S12_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5c_S19_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC5d_S26_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6a_S6_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6b_S13_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6c_S20_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC6d_S27_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7a_S7_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7b_S14_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7c_S21_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", "./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt", 
"./LC7d_S28_R1_001.fastq.bam.txt"), V1 = c(165654L, 536619L, 
886914L, 592837L, 457213L, 2462004L, 1278237L, 100659L, 72829L, 
11249L, 4136L, 80318L, 247149L, 401957L, 261957L, 286761L, 2091422L, 
1108388L, 93913L, 65827L, 11150L, 2502L, 318174L, 1061462L, 1811485L, 
1210305L, 878620L, 3939288L, 2351546L, 158225L, 117326L, 14675L, 
5540L, 172024L, 593898L, 1018580L, 687585L, 647757L, 4176602L, 
2470810L, 189887L, 146039L, 11968L, 3516L, 89984L, 301412L, 547835L, 
371119L, 264558L, 1051806L, 581942L, 35718L, 26930L, 4839L, 2072L, 
88606L, 291013L, 517119L, 345786L, 369304L, 1990210L, 1134278L, 
64767L, 51906L, 4817L, 2853L, 66136L, 201628L, 348762L, 222782L, 
180078L, 782412L, 534609L, 33023L, 25089L, 3530L, 2672L, 116495L, 
404826L, 739835L, 505305L, 329984L, 1176135L, 703200L, 39312L, 
30579L, 2861L, 1804L, 76274L, 132644L, 187678L, 138699L, 139575L, 
786144L, 307708L, 61324L, 32198L, 25416L, 17390L, 56565L, 97607L, 
132726L, 99503L, 107553L, 594492L, 242656L, 48798L, 26411L, 19841L, 
13216L, 106224L, 185532L, 254292L, 190215L, 185612L, 950725L, 
387146L, 82824L, 44857L, 34610L, 24212L, 80653L, 151280L, 214130L, 
152949L, 152028L, 732668L, 326087L, 56925L, 30604L, 22940L, 15337L, 
65624L, 63506L, 63012L, 62432L, 94537L, 542501L, 199773L, 50390L, 
33319L, 28780L, 21440L, 30931L, 30599L, 33469L, 32154L, 61837L, 
423866L, 153656L, 29227L, 17812L, 15582L, 9882L, 72330L, 68392L, 
66251L, 71855L, 134483L, 821465L, 313601L, 69759L, 42804L, 39183L, 
24303L, 30132L, 28149L, 28421L, 30218L, 64633L, 434753L, 156972L, 
32262L, 19623L, 17882L, 10215L, 60948L, 51679L, 53546L, 52003L, 
122091L, 846621L, 335247L, 68272L, 41303L, 39827L, 21242L, 52500L, 
44582L, 45627L, 45003L, 98683L, 678834L, 254330L, 55748L, 34537L, 
32947L, 18775L, 66872L, 59961L, 65387L, 64021L, 183565L, 1482953L, 
540233L, 104624L, 57750L, 56034L, 25371L, 89985L, 78724L, 78204L, 
76423L, 196189L, 1490142L, 663401L, 122447L, 68886L, 66239L, 
31520L, 104702L, 83311L, 82033L, 76787L, 357634L, 4508994L, 1297778L, 
226558L, 103754L, 88664L, 42901L, 67709L, 57989L, 59665L, 58391L, 
221447L, 2708170L, 813083L, 149962L, 73761L, 71477L, 29940L, 
91695L, 79480L, 81337L, 79015L, 266339L, 3049818L, 875796L, 160750L, 
82615L, 76078L, 39481L, 125972L, 100879L, 106032L, 101841L, 375583L, 
4253521L, 1328308L, 245639L, 121382L, 115566L, 51442L, 81596L, 
70944L, 72705L, 62169L, 365046L, 4955005L, 1251638L, 208651L, 
90443L, 71910L, 33530L, 97788L, 109013L, 95285L, 75724L, 454468L, 
7610134L, 1284513L, 222953L, 99587L, 71801L, 52609L, 112676L, 
107146L, 95725L, 77229L, 517338L, 7547254L, 1675259L, 278075L, 
117900L, 88727L, 48426L, 86495L, 87518L, 83651L, 66945L, 521131L, 
7361276L, 1646492L, 269640L, 109625L, 75378L, 40995L), V2 = c(25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L)), row.names = c(NA, -308L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1088078e0>)
```

Any suggestion how to continue to get to my desired output? Thanks !

Comment: Try `DT <- do.call(rbind, sapply(list_of_files, fread, simplify = FALSE) ) `. Its hard to help with no reproducible data.

Comment: I tried and it just erase the last column. I am adding data so its easier to help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work
a = pivot_wider(DT, names_from = FileName, values_from = V1)